# Problem with creating two components from one in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one, larger component that has several state and props. This component is responsible for the header and sidebar. (moves the menu to the left). so I want to split it into two files, but I can not do it well.

This component has const Drawer and that's exactly what I would like to move to another file (along with state and all styles)
This is my one, larger component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
// import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';

const drawerWidth = 240;
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  appFrame: {
    height: 430,
    zIndex: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%'
  },
  appBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  'appBarShift-left': {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth
  },
  'appBarShift-right': {
    marginRight: drawerWidth
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    marginRight: 20
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none'
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: drawerWidth
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
  'content-left': {
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth
  },
  'content-right': {
    marginRight: -drawerWidth
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  'contentShift-left': {
    marginLeft: 0
  },
  'contentShift-right': {
    marginRight: 0
  }
});

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(
  class Header extends Component {
    state = {
      open: true,
      anchor: 'left'
    };

    handleDrawerToggle = () => {
      const open = this.state.open;
      this.setState({
        open: !open
      });
    };

    render() {
      const { classes, theme } = this.props;
      const { anchor, open } = this.state;

      const drawer = (
        <Drawer
          variant="persistent"
          anchor={anchor}
          open={open}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper
          }}
        >
          <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
          <Divider />
          <List component="nav">
            <ListItem button>
              <ListItemText primary="One ListItem" />
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem button>
              <ListItemText primary="Two ListItem" />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Drawer>
      );

      return (
        <div className={classes.appFrame}>
          <AppBar
            className={classNames(classes.appBar, {
              [classes.appBarShift]: open,
              [classes[`appBarShift-${anchor}`]]: open
            })}
          >
            <Toolbar disableGutters={!open}>
              <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="Open drawer"
                onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
                className={classNames(classes.menuButton)}
              >
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
                Example Text
              </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          {drawer}
          <main
            className={classNames(classes.content, classes[`content-${anchor}`], {
              [classes.contentShift]: open,
              [classes[`contentShift-${anchor}`]]: open
            })}
          >
            <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
            <Typography>You think water moves fast? You should see ice.</Typography>
          </main>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

And this is my attempt to split this into two files, but it does not work.
It compiles success, but it does not display correctly.

**Header.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';

const drawerWidth = 240;
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  appFrame: {
    height: 430,
    zIndex: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%'
  },
  appBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  'appBarShift-left': {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth
  },
  'appBarShift-right': {
    marginRight: drawerWidth
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    marginRight: 20
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none'
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: drawerWidth
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
  'content-left': {
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth
  },
  'content-right': {
    marginRight: -drawerWidth
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  'contentShift-left': {
    marginLeft: 0
  },
  'contentShift-right': {
    marginRight: 0
  }
});

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(
  class Header extends Component {
    state = {};

    handleDrawerToggle = () => {
      const open = this.props.open;
      this.setState({
        open: !open
      });
    };

    render() {
      const { classes, theme } = this.props;
      const { anchor, open } = this.props;
      return (
        <div className={classes.appFrame}>
          <AppBar
            className={classNames(classes.appBar, {
              [classes.appBarShift]: open,
              [classes[`appBarShift-${anchor}`]]: open
            })}
          >
            <Toolbar disableGutters={!open}>
              <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="Open drawer"
                onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
                className={classNames(classes.menuButton)}
              >
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
                Example Text
              </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          <Sidebar />
          <main
            className={classNames(classes.content, classes[`content-${anchor}`], {
              [classes.contentShift]: open,
              [classes[`contentShift-${anchor}`]]: open
            })}
          >
            <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
            <Typography>You think water moves fast? You should see ice.</Typography>
          </main>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

**Sidebar.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

    import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
    import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
    import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    // import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
    import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
    import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
    import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';

    const drawerWidth = 240;
    const styles = theme => ({
      drawerPaper: {
        position: 'relative',
        width: drawerWidth
      },
      drawerHeader: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        padding: '0 8px',
        ...theme.mixins.toolbar
      }
    });

    export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(
      class Sidebar extends Component {
        state = {
          open: true,
          anchor: 'left'
        };

        render() {
          const { classes, theme } = this.props;
          const { anchor, open } = this.state;
          return (
            <Drawer
              variant="persistent"
              anchor={anchor}
              open={open}
              classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper
              }}
            >
              <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
              <Divider />
              <List component="nav">
                <ListItem button>
                  <ListItemText primary="One ListItem" />
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem button>
                  <ListItemText primary="Two ListItem" />
                </ListItem>
              </List>
            </Drawer>
          );
        }
      }
    );
```

Comment: You are not passing down any props to the `Sidebar` component, which I assume replaces the `const drawer`.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the state `open` in your header component but you are not passing it down to `Sidebar` component as a prop to control it.

Comment: I can not do it properly. could anyone write me the code correctly so that I could analyze it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm suposing that you choose the Header Component to manage the `open` state property soo:

your header component should be with open and it's function to toggle.

```
class Header extends Component {
  state = {
      open: true,
  };

  handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    const open = this.state.open;
    this.setState({
      open: !open
    });
  };

  render() { ...
    <Sidebar open={this.state.open} anchor="left" />
  }
}
```

and sidebar component should receive the other stuffs from props

```
  const Sidebar = () => {
    const { classes, theme, anchor, open } = this.props;
    return (
      ...
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing down the props, that could be the issue. But something like this should work.

The best way to accomplish this is by using stateless components and pass down the data you need it to render.

You can write the main component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';

const drawerWidth = 240;
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  appFrame: {
    height: 430,
    zIndex: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%'
  },
  appBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  'appBarShift-left': {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth
  },
  'appBarShift-right': {
    marginRight: drawerWidth
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    marginRight: 20
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none'
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: drawerWidth
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
  'content-left': {
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth
  },
  'content-right': {
    marginRight: -drawerWidth
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  'contentShift-left': {
    marginLeft: 0
  },
  'contentShift-right': {
    marginRight: 0
  }
});

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(
  class Header extends Component {
    state = {
      open: true,
      anchor: 'left'
    };

    handleDrawerToggle = () => {
      const open = this.state.open;
      this.setState({
        open: !open
      });
    };

    render() {
      const { classes, theme } = this.props;
      const { anchor, open } = this.state;

      return (
        <div className={classes.appFrame}>
          <AppBar
            className={classNames(classes.appBar, {
              [classes.appBarShift]: open,
              [classes[`appBarShift-${anchor}`]]: open
            })}
          >
            <Toolbar disableGutters={!open}>
              <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="Open drawer"
                onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
                className={classNames(classes.menuButton)}
              >
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
                Example Text
              </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          <Sidebar anchor={anchor} open={open} classes={classes} />
          <main
            className={classNames(classes.content, classes[`content-${anchor}`], {
              [classes.contentShift]: open,
              [classes[`contentShift-${anchor}`]]: open
            })}
          >
            <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
            <Typography>You think water moves fast? You should see ice.</Typography>
          </main>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

And the `Sidebar` component like:

```
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';

const Sidebar = ({ anchor, open, classes }) => (
    <Drawer
      variant="persistent"
      anchor={anchor}
      open={open}
      classes={{
        paper: classes.drawerPaper
      }}
    >
      <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
      <Divider />
      <List component="nav">
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText primary="One ListItem" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText primary="Two ListItem" />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </Drawer>
  );
```